# Cannot install google-breakpad-git in Arch

Tags: linux, archlinux

I'm trying to install Telegram Messenger on my Arch Linux machine, but it keeps spitting out errors at me. Here's the full log:

```
google-breakpad-git r1603.32a9e038-1  (2017-03-08 19:58)
( Unsupported package: Potentially dangerous ! )
==> Edit PKGBUILD ? [Y/n] ("A" to abort)
==> ------------------------------------
==> n

==> google-breakpad-git dependencies:
 - depot-tools-git (already installed) [makedepend]


==> Continue building google-breakpad-git ? [Y/n]
==> ---------------------------------------------
==> y

==> Building and installing package
==> Making package: google-breakpad-git r1603.32a9e038-1 (Thu Aug  3 21:38:58 CEST 2017)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
==> Extracting sources...
==> Starting prepare()...
Running: /usr/bin/python2 /opt/depot_tools/gclient.py root
Running: /usr/bin/python2 /opt/depot_tools/gclient.py config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad.git",
    "managed": False,
    "name": "src",
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Running: /usr/bin/python2 /opt/depot_tools/gclient.py sync

src/src/tools/gyp (ERROR)
----------------------------------------
[0:00:02] Started.
[0:00:02] 

________ running 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp /tmp/yaourt-tmp-yuki/aur-google-breakpad-git/src/google-breakpad-git/src/src/tools/_gclient_gyp_dxYhz1' in '/tmp/yaourt-tmp-yuki/aur-google-breakpad-git/src/google-breakpad-git'
[0:00:02] Cloning into '/tmp/yaourt-tmp-yuki/aur-google-breakpad-git/src/google-breakpad-git/src/src/tools/_gclient_gyp_dxYhz1'...
[0:00:02] remote: Sending approximately 11.43 MiB ...        
[0:00:02] Receiving objects:   0% (1/17918)   
[0:00:02] Receiving objects:  10% (1792/17918)   
[0:00:03] remote: Total 17918 (delta 11275), reused 17918 (delta 11275)        
[0:00:03] Receiving objects: 100% (17918/17918)   
[0:00:03] Resolving deltas:   0% (0/11275)   
[0:00:03] Resolving deltas:  10% (1205/11275)   
[0:00:03] Resolving deltas: 100% (11275/11275)   
[0:00:03] Checked out e8ab0833a42691cd2184bd4c45d779e43821d3e0 to a detached HEAD. Before making any commits
in this repo, you should use 'git checkout <branch>' to switch to
an existing branch or use 'git checkout origin -b <branch>' to
create a new branch for your work.
[0:00:03]
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2509, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2495, in main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/subcommand.py", line 252, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2256, in CMDsync
    ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 1436, in RunOnDeps
    work_queue.flush(revision_overrides, command, args, options=self._options)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 1050, in run
    self.item.run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 889, in run
    self.ParseDepsFile()
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 689, in ParseDepsFile
    gclient_eval.Exec(deps_content, global_scope, local_scope, filepath)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 209, in Exec
    _visit_in_module(stmt)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 193, in _visit_in_module
    value = _gclient_eval(node.value, global_scope, filename=filename)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 173, in _gclient_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 146, in _convert
    for k, v in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.__update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 571, in update
    for key, value in other:
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 146, in <genexpr>
    for k, v in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 146, in _convert
    for k, v in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.__update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 571, in update
    for key, value in other:
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 146, in <genexpr>
    for k, v in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 165, in _convert
    return _convert(node.left) + _convert(node.right)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 167, in _convert
    return _convert(node.left) % _convert(node.right)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 299, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 294, in main
    return run(options, spec, root)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 288, in run
    return checkout.init()
  File "/opt/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 131, in init
    self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 78, in run_gclient
    return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 68, in run
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('/usr/bin/python2', '/opt/depot_tools/gclient.py', 'sync')' returned non-zero exit status 1
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in prepare().
    Aborting...
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build google-breakpad-git.
```

I've also tried to use pacaur, but I get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in gclient_eval.py. I've attached a patch that works for me to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=749720

It is really just a one character change. Look at the patch and you'll see that you just need to change the % to + on line 167. Since your account doesn't have permission to modify the file, you'll need to either change its permissions or use sudo vim (or your favorite editor) to edit it.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but how do I apply this patch?

Comment: Alright, I've figured it out a bit, but now it asks me what file to patch. I enter `gclient_eval.py` and it tells me it cannot find the file...

Comment: I think I've figured it out, but now I'm stuck with the following...

`File /opt/depot_tools/gclient.py is read-only; trying to patch anyway
patch: **** Can't create temporary file /opt/depot_tools/gclient.py.oZ1hSsv : Permission denied
`

Comment: You must edit the file as root. If you have sudo access, you can do sudo vim gclient_eval.py from the appropriate directory. If you do not have sudo, login as root via su then edit the file. If you have neither permission I can't help.